# Can Bonus Character like Marjoly and Priere be fought again in a new Cycle

Tags: disgaea

after the reformatting of my memory stick because all the games but 3 got corrupted i've been looking into downloading a OPed save file so that i can skip to where i was, however a lot of saves have Marjoly and Priere already beaten and in the party

now i was on the first part of the final chapter (War of the Netherworld) so i know i wasn't too far off and i spent quite some time building up Managers and Statisticians for grinding so it's kind of a pain to build that up again, when i get to the chapter i was on i plan to reincarnate all the characters and sell most of the equipment

the main thing though is that i would still want to beat Marjoly and Priere myself, so can i still fight them even though they've been beaten once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fight them again as if you met them the first time.  In fact you have to do this in order to recruit them again.  Though if you win the version that joins you is what you carried over in the previous playthrough.

Comment: in the save i have it's sitting on Chapter 3 and i have them, does that mean that they've been beaten already and i need to wait until a new cycle to beat them again?

Comment: @Memor-X that's correct, though it shouldn't be possible to do it in chapter 3, as you shouldn't be able to pass those bills to open their areas that soon...

Comment: @sparticus is it possible to do it in chapter 3 in a 2nd or 3rd cycle, this is where i got the save http://www.gamefaqs.com/psp/935234-disgaea-afternoon-of-darkness/saves, it's the 2nd one down, i think the save games may be hacked as ones that are in chapter 1 have only Laharl at that Level and not Etna or the Prinnys and i can not see someone grinding the first stage until only Laharl was level 9999

Comment: @sparticus their gone now however the Dark Records still indicate that they have been defeated, does that make any difference